# Ошибка при запуске теста, может кто то сталкивался

Tags: selenium, codeception

> Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.4 Powered by PHPUnit 5.4.8 by
>   Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                                                [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchDriverException]
> ```
>
> no such session
>
> ```
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux
> ```
>
> 4.4.0-46-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)     Command duration or timeout: 15
>   milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13
>   10:48:16 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'by-0040l', ip: '192.168.30.172', os.name: 'Linux',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-46-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111'                                               Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome version must be >=
>   53.0.2785.0
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux
>   4.4.0-46-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]                                                      Session ID: 62d76e527bc716e745db9ed15690a1e7

Comment: помогла установка 16-й убунты =)

Answer (score 0):

Установите `Google Chrome` больше 53 версии, и когда запускаете драйвер то делайте это с правами админа (`Sudo`)